# Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java" (-1)

Tags: java, macos, javac

I am having a pathetic issue with Java in my mac osx 10.7.3 .
Previously I installed it and it was working fine.
After some changes in the .bash_profile and .profile file in the course of time,
I am having an error like

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java"
```

whenever I try to run "javac" or "java" in my terminal .

`echo $PATH` gives an output like :

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/sabya/Documents/Play_Framework/play-2.0:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

My .bash_profile looks like :

```
alias start_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start"
alias stop_mysql="/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

Output of `which java`

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Its bugging me for long days and uninstalling and installing java did not help my luck .

I am a newbie in Mac and need help to sort out this issue .

Googled and saw SOF before posting this question but did not find anything specific to my problem .

Thanks

Sabya

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Most certainly, `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java` is the culprit. This env var should point to the JDK or JRE installation directory. Googling shows that the best option for MacOS X seems to be `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home`.

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home in .bash_profile worked perfectly .Thanks for the help . :-)

Comment: Mine was installed to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me as well, though I don't understand it. If you as for "which java" the console returns /usr/bin/java, then why do we have to set a different path?

Comment: @Loebre: See the answer from Anony-Mousse

Comment: 2019 Update for JDK 11: `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Could you please elaborate on why this worked?

Comment: Sorry, not after 7+ years :)

Answer (score 15):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Because:

```
 $ find /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home -name java*
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javadoc
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javafxpackager
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javah
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javap
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javapackager
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/javafx-src.zip
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 12):

`JAVA_HOME` is **not the name of the java executable**. But of the directory, java was installed in. The executable should be `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java`.

The `which` command is not helpful for you there. It will not give you the java home, but most likely this is just a wrapper or symlink to java installed in a very different directory.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem occurs when I've downloaded `macOS Compressed Archive` which underlying directory contains

```
jdk-11.0.8.jdk
- Contents
  - Home
    - bin
    - ...
  - MacOS
  - _CodeSignature
```

So, to solve the problem, JAVA_HOME should be pointed directly to /Path-to-JDK/Contents/Home.

Answer (score 1):

i have experienced the same problem, and after reading this post i have double checked the `JAVA_HOME` definition in `.bash_profile`. It is actually:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(which java)
```

that, exactly as [Anony-Mousse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1060350/anony-mousse) is explaining, is the executable. Changing it to:

```
export=/Library/Java/Home
```

fixes the problem, tho is still interesting to understand why it's valued in that way in the profile file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Updating bash_profile with the following lines, solved the problem for me:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/'

export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I followed your solution, but terminal didn't save my settings. How should I save the settings on bash profile?

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS Catalina, run

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

In *bash_profile*, add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Verify by running *java --version*

Answer (score 1):

For those using newer versions of java: `jhat` has been removed since Java 9. Source: https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/12/OpenJDK-9-removal-of-HPROF-jhat/

That same article recommends using [Java VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) instead.