# Unable to use Java 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble using eclipse/intelliJ because whenever I try to check java version, this is what I will get. But java is present in the system preferences pane.

```
$ java -version
Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java" (-1)
```

Comment: you have to install java 8 on your machine before

Comment: I have installed Java 8 Update 91. I verified this from System Preferences Pane.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873437/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-usr-bin-java-bin-java-1 Have you tried answers provided in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that java 8 is in your PATH or whatever it is called on windows if you are using windows.

If that's not the problem, consider uninstall and install again java, something might have gone wrong back when you installed it.

It none of this works, could you show us your intelliJ or eclipse settings about Java location ?

Comment: I agree, I tried going back to default version of java that ships with OSX. Hope I can resolve this.

Comment: From what I can read to the answer you gave to @Vaibhav Jain just above, the version currently used by your system is 1.6. That's your problem I guess.

Comment: Yes! I downloaded jdk 1.8 and changed the JDK settings in project structure in IntelliJ and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

**If you're on Mac, do this:**

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

or:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

**Instead of this:**

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
```

or:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/libexec/java_home"
```

Comment: Anybody knows what the /usr/libexec/java_home command does?

Comment: That's not a command, it's a path to a Java executable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like java is installed but classpath is not set. 
please try following command in terminal to set the java path.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Once this is done then check the java version. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello Vaibhav, 

when I tried doing this, it says this:

Last login: Mon May  2 16:57:40 on ttys000

$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)

But when I try again to "Java -version" I get this error 

Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java" (-1)

Comment: Can you please open a new terminal and execute above two lines separately.

Answer (score -1):

I can now run my java programme in IntelliJ Idea.

May be one day I will do the same by helping somebody out.

Solution was:

First I would like to give a context. I had deleted 'Java' folder under

/HDD/library/

On my mac, because I was trying to uninstall all legacy versions of Java. Then on Oracle site, I read that I should have kept default (java 1.6) to facilitate Eclipse installation.

Then:

1. downloaded java 1.6 on apple website - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US
2. used @vaibhav Jain's solution to set/point to my jdk folder instead of default one. By using this:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Dowloaded jdk 1.8 from Oracle website to update my java - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
4. Tried checking the java version on terminal by $ java -version
5. Confirmed that it was showing the updated version.
6. Tried running java programs, and I was able to without any error messages!

Comment: @bengalurean I have edited your question. you have to specify your solution at this answer.