# java -version command giving error on MAC OS

Tags: java, macos, terminal, java-8, java-home

I have installed java 8 on my Mac. But when I type command 'java-version' I get the following error -

> Unable to locate an executable at
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home/bin/java"
>   (-1)

Comment: You type `java-version` or `java -version` ?

Comment: I am using the command java -version . In my /Library/java it is showing 2 java versions. java 7 and 8

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873437/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-usr-bin-java-bin-java-1

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the java home from "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home" to "/Library/Java/Home". Its working now