# Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)

Tags: java, macos, macos-sierra, apt

I have installed JDK in Mac OS.

I am trying to install Apache2,

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Output :-

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

But, executable file is present in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/`

```
$find /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home -name java*

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873437/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-usr-bin-java-bin-java-1?rq=1

Comment: The whole Java thing is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). You have found instructions for installing Apache that are intended for use with a Debian- or Ubuntu-derived Linux distribution, which use `apt` for package management, and `/usr/bin/apt` on a Mac is something else. MacPorts, Homebrew, or Fink are three projects which provide analogous functionality for macOS. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359219/error-when-using-apt-on-macos-sierra) (and [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359221/278323)) for more context.

Answer (score 2):

> I have installed JDK in Mac OS.

Well, `apt` is not an MacOS command for package installation. Wherever you copied those instructions from was for Debian/Ubuntu, not Mac

If you want to install Apache HTTPd on Mac, I'd recommend using Homebrew or Docker. And if using Docker, you don't need Java installed on your Mac

Answer (score -1):

You are not querying for the file they are asking home/bin/apt

If you look in your folder you will not find this file most likely.

Try installing an older version of the sdk.