# jdk and jRE installed but still get Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt

Tags: java, php, apache

i'm trying to install apach lib on my mac os like this

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

i have this error
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

i already installed JDK and JRE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to locate an executable at "/usr/bin/java/bin/java" (-1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873437/unable-to-locate-an-executable-at-usr-bin-java-bin-java-1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually use MacOS but, try your environmental variables.

If you don't get a version back when using the command: `java -version` (without the quotes), the path to java probably isn't set right.

We can further check that this is the case by using the command: `printenv` or `env` to get a print out of all the variables that are pathed on your machine.

You can check to make sure your java is installed in the default location by using
`/usr/libexec/java_home`

Then you can add to the environmental variables list by:

1. Find the path to .bash_profile by using:

> `~/.bash-profile`

2. Open the .bash_profile file with a text editor of your choice.
3. Scroll down to the end of the .bash_profile file.
4. Use the export command to add new environment variables:

> export [variable_name]=[variable_value]

The command should look something like this

> `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

This is just a guess as I again don't use Mac or have access to one

5. Save any changes you made to the .bash_profile file.
6. Execute the new .bash_profile by either restarting the terminal window or using:

> `source ~/.bash-profile`

Comment: when i use this command java -version i can find which version of java is installed, my problem is i can't execut apt command

Comment: Was it in your environmental variables?